# Compare two generic lists using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I'm trying to compare two generic list using following query, just want to insert modified values only

so I wrote following

```
public ActionResult GetModifiedRecords(IEnumerable<SalesOrder> oldSalesOrderList, List<SalesOrder> newSalesOrderList)
{
    var result = (from oldSalesOrder in oldSalesOrderList
                  from newSalesOrder in newSalesOrderList
                  where
                  (oldSalesOrder.Value != newSalesOrder.Value)
                  select oldSalesOrder).Distinct();
    IEnumerable<SalesOrder> modifiedSalesList = new List<SalesOrder>(result);
    return modifiedSalesOrder;           
}
```

but this seems not working

Comment: What you meant by not working? what you found wrong with current code?

Comment: its getting whole record set without comparing

Comment: `var modifiedRecords = newSalesOrderList.Except(oldSalesOrderList);`

You can use this method if your SalesOrder class implements an IComparer that will compare the relevant fields / properties and return if they match

Comment: I want just get changed values only by `oldSalesOrder.Value != newSalesOrder.Value` this condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note : The return type of your Linq Query will be `IEnumerable` you need to not create it again by casting;

Have you tried something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<SalesOrder> GetModifiedRecords(IEnumerable<SalesOrder> oldSalesOrderList, List<SalesOrder> newSalesOrderList)
{
    return oldSalesOrderList.Where((x,i)=>newSalesOrderList[i].Value !=x.Value);  
}
```

Above code will works only if both Lists are of same order, if not you can try something like this(Assume that `OrderId` will be an unique field):

```
return oldSalesOrderList.Where(x =>
       newSalesOrderList.Any(y => y.OrderId == x.OrderId && Y.Value !=x.Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the modified records like so:

```
    var modifiedRecords = newSalesOrderList.Where(a => oldSalesOrderList.All(b => b.Value != a.Value));
```

I dont really understand what you are doing. but based on your question. that should work.

Answer (score 1):

You have the solution on how to do it, from the other answers, but let me explain why your original query was not working. Imagine you call your method with these 2 lists:

```
var list1 = new List<SalesOrder> 
    { new SalesOrder { Value = 1 }, new SalesOrder { Value = 2 } };
var list2 = new List < SalesOrder > 
    { new SalesOrder { Value = 1 }, new SalesOrder { Value = 3 } };
var res = GetModifiedRecords(list1, list2);
```

Your query will take the first item from `list1` and compare it against the first item of `list2` and it will notice they are the same so it will not select it. Then it will compare the first item from `list1` against the 2nd item in `list2` and since they are not equal it will select the first item from `list1` even though you were not expecting this. Then it will do the same for the 2nd item from `list1`. So the end result, it will return both items from `list1` even though you were expecting only the difference.